# Different hosts with same hostname?

Tags: dns, ip, host, hostname

I know that the hostname www.google.com has many IP addresses associated in the DNS. So, let's say I go to www.google.com and the DNS gives me one IP, lets call it 111.11.1.1, so I send my queries to that IP. Then somebody else goes to www.google.com and the DNS gives him another IP, lets call it 222.22.2.2, so he sends his queries to that IP.

I suppose this different IP's are probably for different computers, since www.google.com has many IP addresses asociated for load distribution purposes(so it wouldn't make sense that all the IPs refer to the same computer).

If this is true then I have 2 different hosts(computers) resolving queries for the same hostname, so they have the same hostname, right?

But according to wikipedia a hostname refers only to one device. How comes?

Comment: In this context "hostname" really refers to a *domain name*, which is what you see in the browser address bar, eg. The wikipedia article read may be focused on 'local hostnames', such as what might be found in LAN. See the [Domain Name Systems (DNS) article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for more details on how such works.

Answer (score 0):

A hostname is the name of a particular server or device.

A domain name is what you are referring to. As you noted, this can be load balanced by, for example, using the DNS round robin technique so this resolves to different locations each time.

Comment: So www.google.com isn't a hostname? it is a domain name instead?